# session checking not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use to set the session in my login controller is like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
```

I used a code for checking session in CodeIgniter for all the controllers

```
if(!$this->session->userdata['logged_in'])
{
    redirect("xxx");
} 
else {          
}
```

but this code works fine when I working on the local server but while I uploading it to live server It doesn't work. please help...

Comment: do you have any error message in log on your server ?

Comment: make sure if your session is not getting re-initialised, i have faced such issue once i was having two libraries and both were initializing session

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: or try to echo session_id(); check if it is same on page load/reload

Answer (score 0):

You need load session before you use it

```
 $this->load->library('session');
```

Dont check session in this way

```
   if($this->session->userdata['logged_in']!='')
    {
        redirect("xxx");
    } 
    else {          
    }
```

Comment: Check using above code. Also try to print if the session is having any data `print_r($this->session->all_userdata())`

Comment: It means `$session_data` dosen't have any thing in it.

Comment: but in login controller i set the session

Comment: Can you print that variable and check if data is present or not `print_r($session_data);`

Comment: i can print session value in login controller but can't in other controllers